# force:recordData not loading record on Task

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I have this component, working very well for Contact object

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldsToQuery" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      targetRecord="{!v.record}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      targetFields="{!v.fieldsToQuery}"
                      />
    {!v.fieldsToQuery.Name}
    <br/>

    {!v.fieldsToQuery.Phone}, {!v.fieldsToQuery.MailingState} {!v.fieldsToQuery.MailingPostalCode}<br />
    {!v.fieldsToQuery.MailingCountry}


</aura:component>
```

But i want to do the same (Load record details) for Task object using the following component (the same just fields changing)

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldsToQuery" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      targetRecord="{!v.record}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      targetFields="{!v.fieldsToQuery}"
                      />
    {!v.fieldsToQuery.Subject}
    <br/>

    {!v.fieldsToQuery.Status}


</aura:component>
```

For task object i cannot get the record field values and i cannot understand what i am doing wrong... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) does not support all Salesforce standard objects. For example, the Event and Task objects are not supported.

For a list of supported objects, see the [User Interface API Developer Guide.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm)

> Most User Interface API resources support these objects. Supported objects:

```
Account
AccountContactRelation
AccountPartner
AccountTeamMember
ActionCadence
Asset
AssetRelationship
AssignedResource
AttachedContentNote
BusinessAccount
BusinessMilestone
BusinessProfile
Campaign
CampaignMember
CareBarrier
CareBarrierType
CareProgram
CareProgramEnrollee
Case
Claim
ClaimCase
ClaimItem
ClaimParticipant
Contact
ContactRequest
ContentDocument
ContentNote
ContentVersion
ContentWorkspace
Contract
ContractContactRole
ContractLineItem
CoverageType
Custom Object
CustomerProperty
DataStreamDefinition
ElectronicMediaGroup
Entitlement
EntityArchivingSetup
EnvironmentHubMember
Image
InsuranceClaimAsset
InsurancePolicy
InsurancePolicyAsset
InsurancePolicyCoverage
InsurancePolicyMemberAsset
InsurancePolicyParticipant
InsuranceProfile
Lead
LicensingRequest
LoanApplicant
LoanApplicationLiability
MaintenanceAsset
MaintenancePlan
MarketingAction
MarketingResource
Note
OperatingHours
Opportunity
OpportunityLineItem
OpportunityPartner
OpportunityTeamMember
Order
OrderItem
OrderItemSummaryChange
OrderSummary
OrgMetric
OrgMetricScanSummary
OrgMetricScanResult
Partner
PersonAccount
PersonLifeEvent
PriceAdjustmentSchedule
Pricebook2
PricebookEntry
Producer
ProducerPolicyAssignment
Product2
ProductCoverage
ProductMedia
ProductMedia
Quote
QuoteDocument
QuoteLineItem
RecordType
ResourceAbsence
ResourcePreference
RetailVisitKpi
RetailVisitWorkTask
RetailVisitWorkTaskOrder
SecuritiesHolding
ServiceAppointment
ServiceContract
ServiceCrew
ServiceCrewMember
ServiceResource
ServiceResourceCapacity
ServiceResourceSkill
ServiceTerritory
ServiceTerritoryLocation
ServiceTerritoryMember
Shift
Shipment
SkillRequirement
SocialPost
SurveyInvitation
SurveyResponse
SurveySubject
Tenant
TimeSheet
TimeSheetEntry
TimeSlot
UsageEntitlement
UsageEntitlementPeriod
User
Visit
WebStoreSearchProdSettings
WorkerCompCoverageClass
WorkOrder
WorkOrderLineItem
WorkType
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So another way is to call Apex on init and fetch data this way? Or do you think there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Why you don't call an apex method on load of the page which return the task record you are looking for?

Comment: Yes this is what i am saying in my previous comment. I will do it that way! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, You can accept the answer if it has served the purpose.